# How would I exclude vowels from a string except for vowels at the beginning of a word?

Tags: java

this is a homework question so I would just like some guidance. Here's a snippet of my code. For my homework I need it to exclude all vowels except for those at the start of a word. For example "in quiet area" would print
"in qt ar" My solution doesn't work.

```
public static String modify(String ad) {
    String answer = ""; // variable for the string returned by this method

        if (isVowel(ad.charAt(0))) {
            answer += ad.charAt(0);
        }
        else {
            answer += ad.charAt(0);
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= ad.length(); i++) {

        if (isVowel(ad.charAt(i)) && ad.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            answer += ad.charAt(i);
        }

        if (isVowel(ad.charAt(i))) {
            continue;
        }
        answer += ad.charAt(i);
    }
    return answer;

}
```

Comment: And your problem is ....???  IOOBE?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I did accidentally post the question before pasting in my code, but I edited it right away if that's what you mean.

Comment: So far, you’ve stated you have a homework assignment, and posted some code.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Do you want to exclude vowels at the _beginning_ only, or both at the beginning _and_ end?  Your expected output does not agree with your text question.

Comment: In a string with multiple words it would print out the string without vowels, but what i'm trying to get it to do is check if there is a vowel preceded by a space (which would indicate the start of a new word), and print it anyway. I would assume by using a conditional statement. My solution doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn’t work .... as in wrong results, crash, doesn’t finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your soloution will work. just currect this below line:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ad.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < ad.length(); i++)
```

**i** < **ad.length()**

but u used **<=**

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement on the entire string excluding the first character:

```
String input = "in quiet area";
input = input.substring(0, 1) + input.substring(1).replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]+", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

This is a literal interpretation of what you said:

> I need it to exclude all vowels except for those at the start of a word

Comment: I fail to see how your literal interpretation is different from the intended interpretation.  You've coded "except for those at the start of _the string_", not "except for those at the start of _a word_".

Comment: A better regex would be: `input = input.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!\\b)[aeiou]", "")` ... using a negative lookback `(?<!\b)` to skip replacing a vowel at the start of a word.

Answer (score -1):

public static String modify(String ad) {
    String answer = ""; // variable for the string returned by this method

```
    if (isVowel(ad.charAt(0))) {
        answer += ad.charAt(0);
    }
    else {
        answer += ad.charAt(0);
    }

for (int i = 1; i <= ad.length(); i++) {

    if (isVowel(ad.charAt(i)) && ad.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        answer += ad.charAt(i);
    }

    if (isVowel(ad.charAt(i))) {
        continu
```